# What do I do if I don't know where to ask my question?

Tags: discussion, support

I figure this is probably a common question but I searched and couldn't find anything. So...

What do I do if I don't know where to ask my question? For example, I want to ask: "In terms of laptop battery, is it cheaper to test my android app in an emulator or on a connected device?"

This question could be considered about:

- Best development practices — Programmers
- Android — Android Enthusiasts
- Interfacing a device with a computer — Super User
- Programming in general — SO

In this situation what do I do?

In any situation where the user is unsure what site to ask on, what should be done?

Comment: As to your actual question, why not just try it both ways and see?

Comment: @Gnome:I'm hesitant to do that because I have got a lot of downvotes in the past from guessing.

Comment: I meant as to "which way uses less power", just try both ways on a full battery charge and see which lasts longer.

Comment: @Gnome: Oh ok.  I missed that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't know what site to use, you can always post a question here on MSO with the [site-rec](/questions/tagged/site-rec) tag. Those questions usually get answered pretty quickly.

You can also just post to your best-guess site, and let the migration process take its course if you've guessed incorrectly. Dealing with an occasional migration isn't a bad thing as long as you make a reasonable attempt to pick the best site (e.g. don't ask about shell scripting on Bicycles SE).

Comment: The site-rec tag is perfect.  A reusable solution was exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @Pops This is a great answer, although it is not useful for non-computer related questions. This is what I was looking for, but it had only 89 viewers in 5 years! Isn't it better to make it more it visible? There are 12m questions on stackoverflow.com alone, and there are only ~1200 (0.01%) questions labeled "site-rec".

Answer (score 5):

I'd go with superuser on that one as its more a hardware question than a development question.

If you're not sure, just ask the question on your best bet with a hint that you weren't sure about where to post. Somebody will help you with a suggestion, or it may even get moved automatically. :D

Comment: It is a hardware question, but it would almost exclusively only matter to programmers developing Android apps.

Comment: Agreed. One day my meta rep will catch up with my SO rep.