# Android user-interface question goes where, if anywhere?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

(Asking here per [this advice](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69555/what-do-i-do-if-i-dont-know-where-to-ask-my-question/69594#69594).)

A user [asked about apparent use discrepancies between two Android apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4124194/what-could-cause-a-large-ad-click-discrepancy-between-two-apps). Stack Overflow community suggests that analytics isn't appropriate there. It certainly doesn't [fit on Android Enthusiasts](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2697/what-could-cause-a-wide-discrepancy-in-ad-clicks-between-two-applications).

Does this question have a home on the Stack Exchange? Where?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that this question belongs *anywhere*. If I understand it right, the question is about why one ad gets more clicks then another, this would be a question for a market research, advertisement or user behavior site...which does not exist at SE, not as far as I know.

Comment: Not *my* question, just to be clear. I'm just trying to help out a user get their question to the right spot so it can get the best answers.

Comment: @Al Everett: Whoops...missed that.

Comment: This was actually my question, Al was kind enough to ask this here as I'm new and wasn't sure what to do. I think I agree with you, there doesn't seem to be a SE that fits my question. I suppose I should check the proposals at area 51.