# How do users know where to ask their questions?

Tags: feature-request, search, new-users

How do users know which site to post on?

I think a site-wide search may help.  EG: I'd type a word in the search box, and the return would include sites that have tags for that term, or questions for that term in the title, or questions that have that term in the body.

This is especially important now with a wide range of sites, and some overlap between a few of the sites.

I saw this question: [What do I do if I don't know where to ask my question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69555/what-do-i-do-if-i-dont-know-where-to-ask-my-question) which has some sort of answers.

Comment: What's wrong with Google?

Comment: "I think a site-wide search may help. EG: I'd type a word in the search box, and the return would include sites that have tags for that term, or questions for that term in the title, or questions that have that term in the body." [Wish granted](http://stackexchange.com/sites#)!

Comment: @djechlin - Remember that I'm talking about new users, and naive users.  Lots of people are terrible at using Google, and SE sites don't always reach the first page for searches.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

People don't usually get it hugely wrong. That is, a question about camping might be posted to Travel by mistake, but it's not going to be posted to Physics or Science Fiction by mistake. People generally know their related sites and can quickly comment "this would be a better fit on ..."

It is true that the FAQs are mostly designed to say what does and doesn't belong on a particular site, rather than going in the other order to answer where something happens to belong. That is a hard question to answer. This slightly imperfect approach of expecting you to click around in the footer and read a few FAQs is working, supplemented by people who know the scope of several sites and are willing to close, comment, and migrate (in certain cases) questions that don't belong where they're asked.

Answer (score 9):

There *is* a site-wide search. Go to http://stackexchange.com. Look in the top right corner, and there should be a search bar that has the tooltip "search all sites."

Put your search term in there! It will search questions and answers across all sites.

Once you have ruled it down to a few sites, you can read their <s>FAQs</s> Help Centers, specifically the part about "what kind of questions can I ask here," to decide on which site you should ask on.

If you're *really* not sure, you can ask here on meta with the [site-rec](/questions/tagged/site-rec) tag.

Comment: And don't forget a user can simply browse the list of sites to see if there is a home for their question. Simple but effective — http://stackexchange.com/sites#traffic

Comment: Cool, thank you!

But, still, *How do new users find this site-wide search*?